# Hibernate fails Integer schema validation after the update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin

I used to run spring boot v2.x but now after updating it to 3.1.4 and getting all the new dependencies, it appears there is this annoying thing which is preventing the application to run and fails on boot.

Basically, I have an entity that maps to a column of type integer in Postgres DB, and back to an enum in SpringBoot/Hibernate. The code used to look very simple, just like this:

```
@Column(name = "status") 
var status: StatusEnum,
```

`status` is of type Integer in DB, and this mapping worked perfectly. Then I updated spring boot version to 3.x, and now during both schema validation fails with this error:

> nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [status] in table [xxx]; found [int4 (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [smallint (Types#TINYINT)]"

I thought, OK, it is expecting smallint but it is an integer there, there must be a way to override this behavior, so I tried telling it with `columnDefinition`:

```
@Column(name = "status", columnDefinition = "INTEGER") 
var status: StatusEnum,
```

And error again:

> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [status] in table [xxx]; found [int4 (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [integer (Types#TINYINT)]"

I tried setting in `columnDefinition` other values as well, such as `integer`, `int4`, `int2`, doesn't matter always the same error.

Is it really possible that this default behavior looking for `TINYINT` cannot be overriden and I'll have to change my db defintion?

The dialect set in my `application.yml` is `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` if it is of any value.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html
It may be helpful to look at 3.11 of the latest Hibernate reference.

Answer (score 0):

With the upgrade to Spring Boot 3.x, Hibernate's mapping restrictions are expected to become stricter.

The problem lies in mapping the Enum class to Integer.

By default, the Enum class is set to TinyInt. I think Hibernate is a strict upgrade to that policy. I'll have to look for references.

A temporary solution that comes to mind is to consider changing the Enum class to a utility class and using it like the code below.

```java
@Entity
class Test(
    @Id val word: String,
    @Column(name = "status", columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
    var status: Int
) {
    fun methodA(): Test {
        val customStatusValue = StatusEnum().enum1
        return Test("", customStatusValue)
    }
}

class StatusEnum(
    val enum1: Int = 14,
    val enum2: Int = 15
)
```